# Getting JGroups Message Contents

Tags: jgroups

Is there a way to access the contents field of a message in JGroups?

I've set up a receiver to receive messages from nodes in a cluster. They are receiving sent messages, except that all messages are prefixed with the source.

I'm currently using message.getObject().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the payload in 2 ways:

- As a copy: Message.getBuffer() or
- As the raw buffer: Message.getRawBuffer()

In the latter case, you want to use offset and length as well, e.g.
msg.getRawBuffer(), msg.getOffset(), msg.getLength()

If you call Message.getObject(), JGroups tries to deserialize the payload into an Object, which may or may not be as efficient as you doing your own marshalling.

Comment: Cheers, just what I needed.